# Утвержденного согласно графику – нужна ли запятая и почему?

Tags: пунктуация

"Прошу предоставить мне отпуск <...>. Вместо утвержденного(,) согласно графику отпусков."

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу необходимости в запятой, потому что"утверждённого согласно графику отпусков" - причастный оборот: утверждённого при каких обстоятельствах? Согласно графику отпусков - зависимые слова в обороте.

Однако сам необособленный причастный оборот входит в распространённое дополнение(вместо одного другое), в данном фрагменте он является парцелляцией, а в деловой речи парцелляция нежелательна, следовательно, это грамматическая ошибка (или стилистическая, потому что в разговорном и художественном стилях  парцелляция используется как образное средство)

Чтобы избежать ошибки, нужно ввести всё дополнение в предыдущее предложение:"Прошу предоставить мне отпуск <...>вместо утвержденного согласно графику ".

Answer (score 0):

Советую оформить одним предложением без запятых.

Если вы просите предоставить отпуск согласно графику отпусков, то

**Прошу предоставить мне отпуск ... согласно графику отпусков вместо утвержденного ранее.**

Если вы просите новый отпуск вместо того, что был утвержден согласно графику отпусков, то

**Прошу предоставить мне отпуск ... вместо утвержденного (ранее) согласно графику отпусков.**

Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «вместо», обычно не обособляются (см. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_287)

Answer (score 0):

Предложение **мне кажется некорректным,** так как утверждается не отпуск конкретного лица, а график отпусков всех работников предприятия.

**Предлагаемый вариант**: Прошу предоставить мне отпуск (указать дату) вместо отпуска (указать дату), соответствующего  утвержденному графику отпусков.

Comment: Может вот так еще лучше: Прошу предоставить мне отпуск (указать дату) вместо отпуска (указать дату), указанного в утвержденном графике отпусков.

Comment: Да, так еще лучше и понятнее.  А то люди совсем запутались в канцелярских грамматических формах.